# Map function over T?

Tags: functional-programming, swift

I just started learning Swift and have a question. I found the following block of code in the "The Swift programming language" book:

```
var optionalName: String? = "John Appleseed"
var greeting = "Hello!"
if let name = optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

And then I thought, why should I do `if let name = optionalName { greeting = "Hello, \(name)" }` every time I need to map a function over boxed value? I found `T?` looking very similar to `Maybe a` from Haskell.

So is there any library function for `fmap f boxedValue`? Or am I thinking too functional for Swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your thinking is just fine! Optional defines a map() method, so you can do:

```
boxedValue.map(f)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried `fmap`, `map`, but not `boxedValue.map`. Need to change my mind to fit OOP :)

Comment: You can command-click on the type in Xcode to show a generated 'header' for it, if you want to see what's available :)

Comment: Cool, thanks for advice. Just checked everything. Works as I expected.